# Read portions of an ifstream into a string object?

Tags: c++, string, input, stream

I'm trying to read an `ifstream` into a string, where I can set the number of characters being read. I've read the documentation for `ifstream.get()` and `ifstream.getline()`, but neither of those accomplish what I want.

Given the following string:

> asdfghjklqwertyuiop

I want to read in varying number of characters at a time into a string. I've started like this, but I'm getting an error that there's no function that will take a string as the first parameter:

```
string destination;
int numberOfLettersToGet = 1;

while (inputstream.get(destination, numberOfLettersToGet)){
   //Do something.
}
```

What can I use instead of `inputstream.get()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may like to use `read` and `gcount` member-functions of `std::istream`. `get` appends a zero-terminator, which is unnecessary when you read into `std::string`.

```
std::string destination;
int numberOfLettersToGet = 1;

destination.resize(numberOfLettersToGet);
std::streamsize n = inputstream.gcount();
inputstream.read(&destination[0], numberOfLettersToGet);
destination.resize(inputstream.gcount() - n); // handle partial read
```

Comment: This will only work for the first time because `gcount()` returns the number of characters read on the last input, not the current stream position. If you read a second time you will start out with `n` being 1 (still set from the last read) and `gcount()` returning 1 as well after the read. 1 - 1 = 0 -> empty string. Resizing to `gcount()` after the `read` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

`istream::get` returns the character as an integer, so you simply need to append the returned character as the next character of the string. e.g.

```
while (string.push_back(inputstream.get()))
{ //...
}
```